# Where does href link points to in html code that uses also php (php calendar)?

Tags: php, html, web, calendar

i am trying to adopt an html code that that draws a calendar without events to a code that displays events on the calendar. I understand that the code builds $weeks array which is later in the code used to draw a table. The calendar switches months going back and fort if either < or > pressed on the screen. So my thinking is that $weeks array is reconstructed once < or > is pressed and the code re-draws the calendar.
Where do href in a-tag in the code point to once < or > pressed. Does the code jumps to $prev ($next) line once < (>) is pressed? The code is from the following website https://codingwithsara.com/how-to-code-calendar-in-php/#Video. I also posted the code below.

My thinking to display my events on that calendar is to read my database extracting events, then loop over them using year, month and dates to display correctly on the current page of the calendar.

Thank you.

Argyn

```
<?php
// Set your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

// Get prev & next month
if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
    $ym = $_GET['ym'];
} else {
    // This month
    $ym = date('Y-m');
}

// Check format
$timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
if ($timestamp === false) {
    $ym = date('Y-m');
    $timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
}

// Today
$today = date('Y-m-j', time());

// For H3 title
$html_title = date('Y / m', $timestamp);

// Create prev & next month link     mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)
$prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
$next = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
// You can also use strtotime!
// $prev = date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month', $timestamp));
// $next = date('Y-m', strtotime('+1 month', $timestamp));

// Number of days in the month
$day_count = date('t', $timestamp);
 
// 0:Sun 1:Mon 2:Tue ...
$str = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
//$str = date('w', $timestamp);


// Create Calendar!!
$weeks = array();
$week = '';

// Add empty cell
$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str);

for ( $day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {
     
    $date = $ym . '-' . $day;
     
    if ($today == $date) {
        $week .= '<td class="today">' . $day;
    } else {
        $week .= '<td>' . $day;
    }
    $week .= '</td>';
     
    // End of the week OR End of the month
    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {

        if ($day == $day_count) {
            // Add empty cell
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
        }

        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';

        // Prepare for new week
        $week = '';
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .container {
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
            margin-top: 80px;
        }
        h3 {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        th {
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        td {
            height: 100px;
        }
        .today {
            background: orange;
        }
        th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1) {
            color: red;
        }
        th:nth-of-type(7), td:nth-of-type(7) {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3><a href="?ym=<?php echo $prev; ?>">&lt;</a> <?php echo $html_title; ?> <a href="?ym=<?php echo $next; ?>">&gt;</a></h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>S</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th>T</th>
                <th>W</th>
                <th>T</th>
                <th>F</th>
                <th>S</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($weeks as $week) {
                    echo $week;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what your question is. If you just want to know where the links in the `<h3>` point to, you can look at the href attribute: they point to the current page with the `ym` query parameter set to the values of `$prev` or `$next`. That is what your code on line 6 checks for to determine which month to display.

Comment: so prev (which is <) point to this line in the code $prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp))); What is "ym query parameter" - I was searching uses of a-tag in html and did not find what it means a question mark in front of a name. I see in the code php variable $ym but cannot connect it to ?ym. If you have a link how those query parameters work that would be helpful.

Comment: Query parameters are options passed to the web page via the URL. For example: `http://example.com/test.php?something=this&somethingElse=that`. The `?` separates the URL from the parameters, the `&` separates one parameter from the other. In PHP, these query parameters can be read using `$_GET`. In this example, `$_GET['something']` would be "this" and `$_GET['somethingElse']` would be "that". In your script, `$prev` is the previous month (e.g. "2020-10"), so the `<` link is loading the current URL with `?ym=2020-10` and your script is checking for that on line 6.

Comment: thank you rickdenhaan, working on your comment

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
    $ym = $_GET['ym'];
} else {
    // This month
    $ym = date('Y-m');
}    
$prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
    $next = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
```

You are creating a date Y-m but expecting a Ym format.

Second:
You are creating a really complex way of calculating for you month calculations.
You should look at [datetime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [dateinterval class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [dateperiod class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

You can create a easy overview:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET['ym'])){
    $start  = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date.'-1');
    }else{
    $start  = new DateTime();
     $start->setDate($start->format('Y'),$start->format('m'),1);
    }
    $start->setTime(00, 00);
    $end = clone $start;
    $end->setDate($end->format('Y'),$end->format('m'),$end->format('t'))->setTime(23, 59);
    $prev = clone $start;
$prev->modify("-1 month");
$next = clone $end;
$next->modify("+1 day");
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    
    $period     = new DatePeriod($start,$interval,$end);
?>
```

Then you can you use:

```
<a href="?ym=<?php echo $prev->format('Y-m');?>">&lt;</a>
//AND
 <a href="?ym=<?php echo $next->format('Y-m');?>">&gt;</a>
```

And for the loop:

```
    <?php
foreach($period as $day){
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d');
    }
?>
```

[Code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85d66f210a385e0a16716ff78d447dc8a182dd7e)